# How do I add parameters to a state in React to open a Modal

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am still new to react and still getting things sorted.

Basically, I have a list of Users on my site, and I would like to (for the start) have a modal popup that when open, it should display the name of the User.

I know that if I use `{user.name}` I can display the name in an HTML element, however I cannot get this to work in the Modal.

The code that controls the Modal is as follows:

```
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);

return (
<> 
... Basic HTML

{showModal ? (
       <div
            className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none"
            onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
          >

...

            <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-headline">
              Hello {user.name}
            </h3>

        <span>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </span>

 </>
      ) : null}
    </>
```

If I try to compile it, I get an error saying that `user is not defined.

So I was thinking of using `{showModal(user)` to pass in the `user` object, but that does not work either.

How can I pass the user info into the modal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would add in a `user` object in as a prop, create it as a variable, create it using the hook `useState`, access it via some custom hook, or access it via context.

Not only does the `user` object need to be available and initialized, it will need a field called `name` in order for that to display in the modal. Conventionally the field `name` should be of type `string`. (Though number will work too. Though most people don't want to have their name be a number. Remember 24601?)